# What is the solution of this convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am new to optimization stuffs. I need to formulate and solve this optimization problem.

$$\min \sum_{t\in\mathcal{T}}p_t$$

s.t. $$\sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}}w_t\log_2\left(1+\frac{h}{w_tn_0}p_t\right)\le TR$$

$$\alpha\sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}}w_t\log_2\left(1+\frac{h}{w_tn_0}p_t\right)\le D$$

$$p_t\ge 0$$

Here,
$p_t$ is the optimization variable.

Here, $\alpha$, $h$, $T$, $R$, $\pi$ and $D$ are real and positive. $\mathcal{T}$ is index set with $T$ elements, i.e., $\mathcal{T}=\{1,2,\cdots, T\}$.

Some one please help me to solve this.

Comment: Who are the variables in the problem? From your statement I deduce that $h,T,R,\pi$ and $D$ are constants, but then $\pi TR\leq D$ is not a constraint. What do we know about $w_t$?

Comment: @Magnusseen, Please see the edit in my problem.

Comment: the second constraint is still equivalent with the constant constraint $\alpha TR \leq D$.

Comment: @supinf, If I replace the equal sign with less than or  equal? See the edit..

Comment: Then you can just as well write $.. \leq \min(TR,D)$. Since the constraint will be active at optimality, you can then say $...=\min(TR,D)$ if you want.

Comment: are the $w_t$'s positive, negative or arbitrary?  If they are all negative, your problem is convex.

Comment: Note that it is not a convex program (assuming $w\geq 0$), as $\log$ is a concave operator. Also, the solution is then trivially $p = 0$.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg, is it: left side of constraint 1 <= min(TR, D) or  left side of constraint 1 <= min(TR, D/alpha)?

Comment: You have $\sum_{t\in \mathcal{T}}w_t\log_2\left(1+\frac{h}{w_tn_0}p_t\right)\le \min(TR,D/\alpha)$, which is a convex set if $w\leq 0$, and nonconvex if $w\geq 0$ but trivially optimized by $p=0$